# Portable JNDI name for DataSource

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish

I have a EJB with field

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/sampleDS")
private DataSource ds;
```

and persistence.xml with entry

```
<jta-data-source>jdbc/sampleDS</jta-data-source>
```

I want to make the application easy portable across different Java EE servers. But in JBoss JNDI name has to start with java:/ or java:jboss/. At the same time Glassfish doesn't like symbol ':'. How to achieve portability? I tried to set attribute `use-java-context="false"` for data source instandalone.xml, but it didn't help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks I examined the issue insufficiently. For some reason I cannot use injection

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/sampleDS")
```

I have to lookup data source manually:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/sampleDS");
```

In this case I can use data sources with attribute `use-java-context="true"` and JNDI name `java:/...` or `java:jboss/...`. Prefixes `java:/` and `java:jboss/` are not required for persistence unit too.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that `persistence.xml` is not intended to define your resources. It is intended to reference the resources to be used for your JTA Entity Manager, your persistence units. Yes, instead of referencing a predefined resource, you might be able to define a resource on the fly, but that will make it placed in a context specific to the container you are using.

When using `persistence.xml` to lookup a predefined JNDI resource, you would use following syntax:

```
  <persistence-unit name="mydb" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/mydb</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  </persistence-unit>
```

Just like `@Resource`, the definition of your persistence unit will try to lookup the JDBC Data Source from the existing context in java:comp/env.

Note that to make sure that those resources are available, they should be used with a `resource-ref` in your `web.xml`. This will move them from the global context or application context into `java:comp/env`, providing it a standard JNDI name. In the case of Tomee for example, placing it in the resources.xml makes it already available to your persistence unit, and the `@Resource` tag, but not in `java:comp/env`.

I am still trying to figure out how Tomee handles the catalina/tomcat `context.xml`, for which I am right now clueless.